# How can I print from an iPad to a network printer managed by a Macbook?

Tags: macos, printing, ipad

Is it possible to use a Macbook to manage a network printer such that I can print to it from an iPad?  This [video](https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DP_64MdjFoL0&h=sAQGgWB6H) explains how to do what I want with Windows, but can the same be done with a Mac?

Comment: Is this really a bad question deserving a down vote? Why?

Comment: Down vote is probably because this seems like a common issue and you could probably solve it yourself with some research. Take a look at [this](http://www.techradar.com/news/networking/how-to-share-a-printer-using-os-x-919718) and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6062956).

Comment: @Adam: Those links (and my own google searching) suggest to me that a question here is completely appropriate, as there's not a single, concise answer that I've yet to find.

Comment: I like the question, and the research about "Airprint for Windows".  Didn't know that existed.  I've upvoted the question, and am curious about the answer.  Just out of curiosity's sake, though, as I have an Airprint-compatible printer, and it was worth it. Look at the CP1525nw for a great network/Airprint color laser printer at a reasonable price.